# POST request from Android not received in Symfony controller

Tags: php, android, symfony, request

I'm having an issue retrieving POST data in a Symfony Controller.

Whenever I print post, get or file variable, arrays are empty.

EDIT : I'm testing this in a local environment using 10.0.2.2

Here's where I send data :

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(mContext.getString(R.string.url_home) + "en" + mContext.getString(R.string.save_sentences_route) + "/add");
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "A"));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    Log.i("TEST", "Passed httpClient.execute");
} 
catch (Exception ignored)
{
}
```

And here's how I receive it in the Symfony Controller :

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
if (!is_object($user) OR !$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'))
{
return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('test_core_default_index'));
}

$all_users = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyUserBundle:User');
$all_users = $all_users->findAll();

var_dump($_GET);
echo "</br></br></br><hr></br></br></br>";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</br></br></br><hr></br></br></br>";
var_dump($_FILES);
echo "</br></br></br><hr></br></br></br>";

//deliberate bug in order to see the var_dumps and echos
return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('deliberate_bug'));
```

I first tested with these instead of $_POST and $_GET:

```
$this->getRequest()->request->all();
$this->getRequest()->query->all();
```

and with these as well :

```
$request->get('text');
$request->get('A'); //I was really desperate trying this.
```

Also tested $_FILES, "just in case".

I don't really what I'm doing wrong. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the cors ? 
You can do it easily with this bundle
[NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle)

Comment: I didn't since I wanted to get it working with the less bundle possible.
I'll look into it though, since nobody answered yet except you. Thanks :)

Comment: you can define it within the htaccess but for me this bundle is helpful